# How to redirect all invalid URLs to some action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Home controller with `Index()` and `Foo(int id)` actions and routings like these:

```
routes.MapRoute("Foo", "{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Foo" });

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

So URLs like `/` and `/123` work as they are supposed to do. However when the URL is `/blahblah` where `blahblah` is not a valid action name I get the error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

which is normal of course because the `Foo` action gets int parameter instead of int?

The problem is I can't use int, because then both the `Index` and `Foo` actions match `/` URL, so there is additional unnecessary `Foo` call.

So the question is, is it possible to catch the exception above OR redirect all not valid URLs like `/blahblah` to some other action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constrain the `id` token on your `Foo` route definition to a number:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Foo",
    "{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Foo" },
    new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

Now:

- `/` will hit `HomeController/Index`
- `/123` will hit `HomeController/Foo` and pass `id = 123` as argument
- `/foobar` will return a 404

Comment: Wow, didn't know this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

IF you define your Home's Index function like following with string id

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    ...
}
```

Then, all your URLs including the /blahblah will point to it.